# problem with vba macros code not equal to checking in decimal values

Tags: vba, ms-access

In Macros coding, i am checking the not equal to condition.  Values are in decimal or integer, Now i compare the two values in decimal values but not get the proper result.  Please guide me what is the thing should be added for getting corrected result?

My code is :

```
 If fld4 <> fldval Then
    MsgBox "....."
 End If
```

But the output of message showing for the following values :

```
fld4 = 0.25, fldval = 0.26
fld4 = 0.25, fldval = 0.25
fld4 = 0.14, fldval = 0.14
fld4 = 0.11, fldval = 0.11
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Never ever (!) compare floating point values directly. Better try something like this:

```
 eps = =.00001 'choose an appropriate epsilon
 If Abs(fld4- fldval)<eps Then
   '...
```

[Look here](http://www.cygnus-software.com/papers/comparingfloats/comparingfloats.htm) for further information.

Comment: Thanks a lot.  I just use Abs and got correct result.  Now my code is 

If Abs(fld4) <> Abs(fldval) Then

Is it enough or anything to be added?

Comment: If Abs used the way you show it gives you an answer, it suggests that you may have negative numbers: http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Absolute_value That is _not at all_ what Doc Brown shows. Depending on what the data refers to, you may find Round(nn.nn, nn) suits.

Comment: @Karthik: using Abs(fld4) <> Abs(fldval) normally won't work, that is an expression that still compares 2 floating point values - DON'T DO THIS!!!. You should really try it the way I wrote in my answer, and invest some time to read the article I gave you a link to.